# Cannot find module executing gulp for laravel windows

Tags: json, node.js, laravel, gulp

I am following [this](https://laracasts.com/series/build-project-flyer-with-me/episodes/3) laracasts video. Here is my 
package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"    
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I installed gulp using

```
npm install gulp
```

Then I executed:
npm install in the project root directory for installing the dependencies in package.json

Now when I execute gulp, I get this error:

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/lang/isFunction'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\PhpIdeaProjects\LaravelLearning\myproject-flyer\no
de_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\lib\api\
node.js:21:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Then after some research, I execute `npm install theMissingModuleName` (Here theMissingModuleName is `lodash/lang/isFunction`) which runs successfully. But again when I run gulp, I get another missind module error(For different module). I install that then it gives another.....
This cycle continues.

I have already installed gulp locally using `npm install gulp -g` and placed `C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm` directory in path.

So now what should I do to avoid these recursive errors?

Comment: Try with removing the local `node_modules` directory and reinstalling the packages.

Comment: I have already created a fresh project altogether. So no use :( . @Vohuman

Comment: On Mac OS X it works well without any problem.

Comment: Maybe you should migrate from Windoze to a real OS.

Comment: @Vohuman thats not at all practical for me.

Comment: You might be experiencing the max character limit for paths in windows (260 characters): https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6960

Comment: @Quy you seem correct. When I try to delete the node_modules directory, I get the max filename length exceeded error.

Comment: I'm not on windows anymore but when I was, I would rename node_modules to n_m or something short. Doesn't solve the problem but it at least gives you some breathing room. There must be a solution by now though.

Comment: @Quy can you please elaborate on this? how does naming node_modules to n_m helps(or should help)?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have updated `npm` to the latest version:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

Then check you have version 3.x.x installed:

`npm -v`

As of 3.0.0 `npm` has a flat directory structure so you shouldn't run in to max character limit issue.

After you have updated, just delete your `node_modules` and do:

`npm install`

in the root of your project.